# Why creating Popup dialog with custom component passed in constructor showing blank Dialog when .show() is called?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am developing a Harmony application where I want to create a popup dialog with a custom component.

I tried this

```
Component customComponent = LayoutScatter.getInstance(context)
                .parse(ResourceTable.Layout_custom_dialog, null, false);
// I have already made custom component
PopupDialog popupDialog = new PopupDialog(getContext, customComponent);
popupDialog.show();
```

After running this I only see a White background Box and Custom Component is not visible.
Why `new PopupDialog(getContext, customComponent);` is not setting customComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check height and width of custom component is properly set.

Or you can assign values when instantiating popup dialog like -

PopupDialog popupDialog = new PopupDialog(getContext(), associated, width, height);

Also, you’ll need to set custom component to popup dialog before show like -

popupDialog.setCustomComponent(component);

Here is an example from the HarmonyOS developer website

https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/faq-java-developing-0000001073311795

Answer (score 0):

```
new PopupDialog(getContext, customComponent);
```

The above constructor call will only acquire the height and width of customComponent that is passed in the constructor.

To customize the content of the popup dialog, you need to use the following API

```
public PopupDialog setCustomComponent​(Component customComponent)
```

You may refer this [documentation](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/popupdialog-0000001054120016#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001054120016__setCustomComponent-ohos_agp_components_Component-) for additional information